# how to safely write mmap'd region to file

Tags: c, linux, signals, mmap, sigbus

I have a generic tool that is meant to dump various information about a process at an arbitrary point in time.   I have hit a bug, where a process being dumped had mmap'd an area of memory to a file, and then the file itself shrunk.   So when I mmap to the same file, my mmap region is bigger than the file.   When I attempt to dump the mmap'd region to file (via `gzwrite`), I get a SIGBUS.

I've considered several solutions, each of which seem to have flaws that I can't get past:

1. write a sigbus handler:

   The sigbus occurs deep within the gzwrite operation, and doing some sort of jump out of the routine would cause the file being written to to become corrupted.   I also do not see any async-safe functions to generate the missing page(s) and simply return.
2. use fstat to get file size, and only read the populated part of the memory region:

   This seems to suffer from concurrency issues -- namely, what happens if the file size shrinks right after I do the fstat call?  I could potentially lock the file from being resized, but I'm worried this might cause other insurmountable issues with other running processes currently using the file.

I'm wondering if there is any safe strategy to dump the contents of the file?

----- EDIT -----

So some simplified code of what the program is doing, or attempting to do:

```
    // grab relevant segment from pid:
    segment = get_prog_seg(pid);

    if (segment->filename) {
       ECHO( "segment: size:%zu, filename:%s", 
             segment->size, segment->filename);

       int mmap_fd = open(segment->filename, O_RDWR);
       if (mmap_fd == -1) { ... };

       // at this point, segment is 500Mb, but the
       // filesize has already shrunk to 100Mb

       mmap_addr = mmap(NULL,
                        segment->size,
                        PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                        MAP_PRIVATE,
                        mmap_fd,
                        segment->file_offset);
       if (mmap_addr == MAP_FAILED) { ... };
       
       int elems_wrote = gzwrite(gzfile, mmap_addr, segment->size);
       // I get a SIGBUS here, as soon as zlib attempts to access 
       // mmap[100Mb]
       ...
    }
```

Comment: I'm not quite following the nature of the failing behavior.  It's not clear to me why or how "dump[ing] various information about a process" is sensitive to the target process's memory mappings.

Comment: if you mmap to a file, and then that file shrinks, then memory access to any of the upper pages that no longer map to the file causes undefined behavior -- in practice, on modern Linux distributions, this means a SIGBUS.    In my case, I know that the dumpee has a 500Mb map to a file, so I copy that mmap.  But then the file shrinks to 100Mb, so the top 400Mb of the mmap becomes invalid.

Comment: I know about `mmap`.  I *don't* know about the details of your program's behavior.

Comment: Silly question maybe but is one size the uncompressed size and the other size is the compressed size? If you use `gzwrite` and sum up the return values, you get the uncompressed size. What's on disk will however be a smaller, compressed, file.

Comment: No, the SIGBUS occurs before `gzwrite` completes, thus I don't even know the compressed size.   The same issue would occur if I used a simple `write` instead.

Comment: I think you need some kind of mutual exclusion mechanism to keep the other processes from shrinking the file while you have it mapped. I don't think there's a good way to deal with the error after the fact.

Comment: More generally, files that are mmap'ed shouldn't be shrunk.